# How do you use socket.io in an Express.js sub app?

Tags: express, socket.io

Because socket.io relies on the server object and the sub-app doesn't have it's own server I was wondering how you would do this?

I hoping that maybe there was a app.on('start') event that has access to the server object but it doesn't look like that's the case.

Comment: Can you just pass the `server` object into the code for your sub-app, so the sub-app has `server` in scope? if you don't have access to `server` yet, maybe define `function subApp.initSocket(server,callback)` and call later?

Comment: It seems to be the only way. Was trying to avoid that because it was a little dirty API wise but guess I'll have no other choice.

Comment: @Pickels I am having exactly the same question. The way I am doing it now is:

    `var server = Http.createServer(app);`
    `require("./subapp")(site, server);`